# Unresolved reference for imported identifiers that are later rewritten

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-import

When I import a function at the top of my file and later use it in a function, in which I reassign it later on, python complains about `Unresolved reference '_'`, e.g.:

```py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def test():
    msg = _('Message')  # <= Unresolved reference '_'

    instance, _ = Something.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

what's happening here? Why python says `Unresolved reference` when evaluating the function, when it is only reassigned later on the next line?

Comment: maybe do not use `_` ? Its generally used as "meh, dont care" resolver

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes that would fix it, but I'm interested in *why* it's happening here. Funnily enough, `_` is generally used for Django translations too, that's how I encountered the error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all but a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370357/8586227), but since PyCharm generates a different error message this will be an answer.

Since you assign to `_` in your function, *all* uses of `_` in that function refer to the local variable rather than to the global (the imported function).  PyCharm recognizes this and can’t identify a type for it to have.